# Export only a single developer account to a .developerprofile from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I've got multiple team accounts in my Xcode on account of some bespoke work. As part of this, I've routinely got to give access to the customer's account to them and the Xcode 6 feature to completely bundle up all required certificates, provisioning profiles and private keys all together in a .developerprofile file is quick and effective.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to export only a single account's developerprofile. Not matter what I do *all* developer accounts are exported. I currently use the following workaround process, where I:

1. Export all accounts to a "full" profile.
2. Delete all accounts except the one that I actually want to export.
3. Export the target account to a separate accountname.developerprofile and send it off to the recipient.
4. Delete the remaining account and import the earlier "full" profile back and I'm back to where I started.

Apple has finally made an export process that works well, and I can't believe how they did not anticipate the need to export only a single account. Is there no way (not even command line) to do this?

Comment: It's not clear why you have multiple developer accounts?  Sounds like this is the root-cause of the issue as it's expected you have a single account.  Therefore probably deleting all but your account will solve the issue.

Comment: I have multiple developer accounts because of bespoke development, as stated. At least one account per each company that I work for. This is required because obviously each company wants their name to appear as developer instead of my company's.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do it as a singe .developerprofile.  If you want a single file approach, you're process is probably the best way to do it.

However, all a developerprofile is is a combination of a key, certificate, and provisioning profile (or profiles).  If you want to set up a developer for each company, you could export the private key (that was used to create the certificate) from Keychain Access into a .p12 file.  Then you could export the developer and/or distribution certificate from Keychain Access as well into a .cer file.  Finally, you would also download any .mobileprovision files that the developer would need to the app in question.

Zip up those 3 files and you basically have a homemade .developerprofile.  The key will need to be password protected, but so did the .developer profile, so it really isn't that much more inconvenient.  And it will save you from having to jump through hoops every time you need to provide the company their own files.  I would recommend any company you work with should be generating their own private key, but I guess most companies that hire out their app development don't have resources that would know to do that.

Also, if you wanted to script the exporting from keychain access, I'm sure you could.  Here's a good starting point: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2551691?tstart=0

Good luck.